# Need help parsing string in bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a script that uses sensors to get CPU temps in Ubuntu.

```
IN="`/usr/bin/sensors -f | grep 'Core ' | cut -f2 -d"+" | cut -f1 -d '.'`"
echo $IN
```

It yields results like this

```
96 100 98 102
```

What I need to do is be able to call it like cpu1 to get the first, cpu2 to get the second, and so on. I need to split it up so i can monitor core temps using MRTG, there might be a better way, but I havent found one yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert `$IN` to an array like this:

```
TEMPERATURES=($IN)
```

Then you can index into that array to get a particular temperature; for example:

```
echo ${TEMPERATURES[0]}
```

If you pass a command-line parameter to your script, you can use that as an array index:

```
WHICH=$1                       # 1st command line arg; $0 is name of script
TEMPERATURES=($IN)
echo ${TEMPERATURES[$WHICH]}
```

Calls to the script might then look like this (assuming the script is called `cpu`):

```
$ ./cpu 0
96
$ ./cpu 1
100
$ ./cpu 2
98
$ ./cpu 3
102
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IN="96 100 98 102"       

I=0
for val in $IN; do
  I=$((I+1))
  eval "cpu$I=$val"
done

echo $cpu1
```

I answered literally how to get $cpu1 etc, but I suggest you do what @Richard suggests and use arrays :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using lots of pipes to extract the cpu temp, you can do it in one single piping with awk:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/sensors -f | awk -F"[+.]" -v c="^Core $1" '$0~c{print $2}'
```

Usage:

```
$./cpu 0
$./cpu 1
$./cpu 2
```